# How to run automated stdin input when running Java program in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, command-line, configuration, intellij-idea, pipe

I'm developing a Java program in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.  To run the program at command-line

```
$ echo 1 a b | java MyProgram 3
```

The `3` is an argument, and when `MyProgram` started, it expects `1 a b` being input at stdin.  How do I set up a Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ IDEA so the above can be simulated in the IDE?

Comment: Not sure how IntelliJ IDEA stores projects, but would it be possible to open the shell, `cd` to where the class files are stored in the project directory, and run the command there?

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. Sorry.

Comment: I am not sure you can piping is usually handled by the shell. You could add a test mode where it reads the data from a file instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate input from stdin when running a program in intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437181/simulate-input-from-stdin-when-running-a-program-in-intellij)