# Executing nothing Java Project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I have the following project in Intellij with the following structure

```
  C:.
  ├───.idea
  │   ├───copyright
  │   ├───dictionaries
  │   └───libraries
  ├───data
  ├───lib
  ├───out
  │   └───production
  │       └───Java Algorithms
  └───src
```

I'm trying to execute the following code

[Binary Search in Gist Github](https://gist.github.com/Davidnet/fd2c5297a0361d5daf5b)

In the data folder I have two archives [tinyW.txt](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/tinyW.txt) and [tinyT.txt](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/tinyT.txt)

And in the lib folder I have the [algs4](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/) jar library, I put the link to the StdIn where I think the problem resides.

And as you can see in the gist I go BinarySearch 'Edit configurations' and in the 'Program arguments' I use

```
data/tinyW.txt < data/tinyT.txt
```

So when I Run the program, I think it keeps doing nothing but the virtual process machine is still running.

I tried to find the problem using debug, and I check that the arguments are ok, that is,

```
args[0] = tinyW.txt
args[1] = <
args[2] = tinyT.txt
```

The tinyW.txt gets parsed ok, but when the debuger gets to this line

```
while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
```

It does nothing and doesn't show me any available options.

I was wondering if anyone could lend a hand on how to run correctly this kind of programs in IDEA.

Thanks.

Comment: It is in this site http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/ left part Search for StdIn

Comment: @Makoto http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.html I found the javadoc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate input from stdin when running a program in intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437181/simulate-input-from-stdin-when-running-a-program-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA run configurations do not support redirecting the standard input from a file. You need to either change your code so that it reads from a file directly, or run your program from the command line outside of IntelliJ IDEA.