# IntelliJ IDEA: Run java with args from external file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to run a java class with args supplied as a file.

On shell, i can do

```
    java SomeClass < 1.txt
```

Is there any equivalent for this on intellij and/or gradle.

I tried on IntelliJ IDEA -> edit configurations. But, the argument is not getting passed.

Answer (score 22):

**UPDATE**:

This feature is now available for some Run/Debug configurations. At the moment supported types for Java-based run configurations are: Application, Java Scratch, JUnit, JarApplication.

Use the **Redirect input from** option:

[image: Redirect input from]

---

Original answer from 2017 with the workaround:

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it at the moment:

- [IDEA-88717](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88717) No way to configure STDIN reading from a file at Run/Debug configurations

You can adjust the code so that it accepts the file name as a parameter and opens it for reading. Or you can create a wrapper class that will redefine `System.in`, then start your original `Main` class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainWrapper {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("1.txt"));
    System.setIn(is);
    Main.main(args);
  }
}
```

Make sure to either specify the full path to the file or to change the working directory in IntelliJ IDEA Run/Debug configuration to the location of `1.txt`.

Now you can run `MainWrapper` class instead of the `Main` class and it will work the same as running

```
java Main < 1.txt
```

If you need to test with different file names, replace `new File("1.txt")` with `args[0]` and pass the file name in the `MainWrapper` Run/Debug configuration **Program arguments** field.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a built-in feature, not a "bolt-on" work-around.  Eclipse has been able to do this for years, but it appears JetBrains has no intention of ever making this a built-in feature of IntelliJ.

Comment: why create a new wrapper class?  Just use System.setIn() in your existing main.

Comment: @johnktejik so that you don't have to modify the existing application behavior.

Answer (score 15):

You can actually do that now, [starting from version 2018.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196611):
 - Select "Run/Debug configurations"
 - Set path to input file at "Redirect input from" field

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `< 1.txt` syntax mean that the command processor ensures that standard input (`System.in` in Java) provides the contents of the 1.txt file.  The typical Java launcher do not support this.

You can emulate this by manually rewire `System.in` to read from the file using your own Java snippet to do this.