# Why does not `< input.txt` work in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just tried to add "< /path/to/file.txt" to `Program arguments` in IntelliJ IDEA settings. My program reads standard input using `Scanner` class and in console similar option works:

```
java -classpath out/my/project Main < input.txt
```

Due to IDEA console it uses correct command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/bin/java -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-182.3911.36/lib/idea_rt.jar=41093:/opt/idea-IU-182.3911.36/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/daniel/Desktop/untitled/out/production/untitled Main < /home/daniel/Desktop/untitled/test.txt
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`< input.txt` is a shell (bash) operation.  When you use this in bash, files are opened and STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR are redirected for the command you run.  You will have to do this yourself in a wrapper command.

Feature Request is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88717

Workaround is [IntelliJ IDEA: Run java with args from external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867756/intellij-idea-run-java-with-args-from-external-file/42869805#42869805)