# Issue Reading data input files from IntelliJ (as a run configuration or from Terminal) from an imported Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

While reviewing the Union Find algorithms that Dr. Robert Sedgewick and Dr. Kevin Wayne instructed via their book and website:

https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/10fundamentals/

I created a Maven project (which I imported into IntelliJ IDEA) with the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.princeton.cs.algs4</groupId>
    <artifactId>algs4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>  <!--javadoc shows all classes and members-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stylesheetfile>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc/stylesheet.css</stylesheetfile>
                    <show>public</show>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

---

Project File Structure:

```
algs4
|
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── edu
    │   │       └── princeton
    │   │           └── cs
    │   │               └── algs4
    │   │                   ├── QuickFindUF.java
    │   │                   ├── QuickUnionUF.java
    │   │                   ├── StdIn.java
    │   │                   ├── StdOut.java
    │   │                   └── WeightedQuickUnionUF.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── largeUF.txt
    │       ├── mediumUF.txt
    │       └── tinyUF.txt
    └── test
        └── java
```

---

QuickFindUF.java:

```
public class QuickFindUF {
    private int[] id;    // id[i] = component identifier of i
    private int count;   // number of components

    public QuickFindUF(int n) {
        count = n;
        id = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            id[i] = i;
    }

    public int count() {
        return count;
    }

    public int find(int p) {
        validate(p);
        return id[p];
    }

    // validate that p is a valid index
    private void validate(int p) {
        int n = id.length;
        if (p < 0 || p >= n) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index " + p + " is not between 0 and " + (n-1));
        }
    }

    public void union(int p, int q) {
        validate(p);
        validate(q);
        int pID = id[p];   // needed for correctness
        int qID = id[q];   // to reduce the number of array accesses

        // p and q are already in the same component
        if (pID == qID) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
            if (id[i] == pID) id[i] = qID;
        count--;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = StdIn.readInt();
        QuickFindUF uf = new QuickFindUF(n);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if (uf.find(p) == uf.find(q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + " components");
    }

}
```

---

QuickUnionUF.java:

```
public class QuickUnionUF {
    private int[] parent;  // parent[i] = parent of i
    private int count;     // number of components

    public QuickUnionUF(int n) {
        parent = new int[n];
        count = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            parent[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public int count() {
        return count;
    }

    public int find(int p) {
        validate(p);
        while (p != parent[p])
            p = parent[p];
        return p;
    }

    // validate that p is a valid index
    private void validate(int p) {
        int n = parent.length;
        if (p < 0 || p >= n) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index " + p + " is not between 0 and " + (n-1));
        }
    }

    public void union(int p, int q) {
        int rootP = find(p);
        int rootQ = find(q);
        if (rootP == rootQ) return;
        parent[rootP] = rootQ; 
        count--;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = StdIn.readInt();
        QuickUnionUF uf = new QuickUnionUF(n);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if (uf.find(p) == uf.find(q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + " components");
    }

}
```

---

WeightedQuickUnionUF.java:

```
public class WeightedQuickUnionUF {
    private int[] parent;   // parent[i] = parent of i
    private int[] size;     // size[i] = number of elements in subtree rooted at i
    private int count;      // number of components

    public WeightedQuickUnionUF(int n) {
        count = n;
        parent = new int[n];
        size = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            parent[i] = i;
            size[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    public int count() {
        return count;
    }

    public int find(int p) {
        validate(p);
        while (p != parent[p])
            p = parent[p];
        return p;
    }

    // validate that p is a valid index
    private void validate(int p) {
        int n = parent.length;
        if (p < 0 || p >= n) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index " + p + " is not between 0 and " + (n-1));  
        }
    }

    public void union(int p, int q) {
        int rootP = find(p);
        int rootQ = find(q);
        if (rootP == rootQ) return;

        // make smaller root point to larger one
        if (size[rootP] < size[rootQ]) {
            parent[rootP] = rootQ;
            size[rootQ] += size[rootP];
        }
        else {
            parent[rootQ] = rootP;
            size[rootP] += size[rootQ];
        }
        count--;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = StdIn.readInt();
        WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int p = StdIn.readInt();
            int q = StdIn.readInt();
            if (uf.find(p) == uf.find(q)) continue;
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
        }
        StdOut.println(uf.count() + " components");
    }

}
```

---

Implementation for StdIn can be found at:

https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdIn.java.html

---

Implementation for StdOut can be found at:

https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdOut.java.html

---

Data files can be found at:

- https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/tinyUF.txt
- https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/mediumUF.txt
- https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/largeUF.txt

---

When I conduct a `mvn clean install` or `mvn test`

It created the appropriate target directory, as follows:

```
target
    ├── classes
       ├── edu
       │   └── princeton
       │       └── cs
       │           └── algs4
       │               ├── QuickFindUF.class
       │               ├── QuickUnionUF.class
       │               ├── StdIn.class
       │               ├── StdOut.class
       │               └── WeightedQuickUnionUF.class
       ├── largeUF.txt
       ├── mediumUF.txt
       └── tinyUF.txt
```

---

Since, I created and imported this into IntelliJ as a maven project, I couldn't figure out how to setup a "Run as a standalone Java application" (with the txt file as args to the main() method.

So, what I did was issue a "mvn test"

Nothing happened... Is there a way to do this via Terminal or IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running in terminal use `java edu.princeton.cs.algs4.QuickFindUF < tinyUF.txt` or `cat tinyUF.txt | java edu.princeton.cs.algs4.QuickFindUF`.

For running in IntelliJ IDEA use the [Redirect input from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pUdW.png) option. Note that the path is relative to the working directory.

> I can't see the Application configuration that Crazy Coder referred

You can create a new Application or Jar Application configuration in IntelliJ IDEA by [clicking the + button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6tZ9.png). [See help for details](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

> When I tried that, it couldn't find the jar file located inside the target directory.

JAR file will be available in the target directory after you run `mvn package` goal. You can do it from the command line Maven or [from the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html). It's also possible to [set up a trigger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html#trigger_goal) to build the jar before run/debug or add this Maven goal to the [Before Launch steps of the run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly).

[See also my other answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42869805/104891). It suggests another way to do it without redirect option using the wrapper class.