# Why does this program throw NoSuchElementException in IntelliJ Debug mode?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I have the following code Groovy code:

```
class Main
{
  static void main(String[] args) {
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()
  }
}
```

When I run this program in IntelliJ, and stop it immediately, I do not see any errors or warnings.

When I run debug this program in IntelliJ, and stop it immediately again, I will see the following in the console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65141', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65141', transport: 'socket'
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at java_util_Scanner$nextLine.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at biz.tugay.cli.Main.main(Main.groovy:6)
```

I want to understand why this behaviour happens in debug mode and what I can do to prevent it.

I am using `openjdk version "1.8.0_292"` and `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3` on `macOS Big Sur`, if any of this matters.

When I convert the code to Java, the stack trace changes slightly but the behaviour is same:

```
Exception in thread "main" Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65185', transport: 'socket'
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at biz.tugay.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: Why is IntelliJ relevant here? Does everything work fine outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: i believe that because you are not providing STDIN when in code you are reading from  `System.in`.. so, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867756/intellij-idea-run-java-with-args-from-external-file/42869805#42869805