# Intellij stdin rederection

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, intellij-idea, cmd

What is a difference how Idea run Batch configuraton compare to pure cmd.exe in windows?

I create batch config for run my java app. When I run it, it show me result scipt in Idea console:

```
cmd.exe /c java -classpath C:\app;C:\app\libs.jar App < input.txt
```

This app waiting input from standard input. This line should run it and read from input.txt file. But insted of reading it waiting for input. When i press ^D in Idea console, App prints me that No inputs was.

In same time when i copy paste this starting script from Idea console direct to Windows cmd, everything happen as expected, App reads the file and finish correctly.

I did read stackoverflow answers and find suggestions to try External Tool Idea option. I try run it as:

```
java -classpath C:\app;C:\app\libs.jar App < input.txt
```

But it still waiting for input. As well as Java Application run configuration if I pass file name as argument, it wait for input:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java"
 -Didea.launcher.port=7533
"-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IDEA\bin"
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 -classpath "long..long..classpath"
 com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Col < input.txt
```

I did find few links ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188547/eclipse-reading-stdin-system-in-from-a-file),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018813/passing-string-buffer-to-java-program-in-intellij-debug-run),[three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437181/simulate-input-from-stdin-when-running-a-program-in-intellij)) about stdin rederection and it seems like there is no way to do this from idea only from code.
Thank you!

Comment: The only way I did find is pass filename as argument and add like at beginning of main something like: `if(args.length > 1)System.setIn(new FileInputStream(args[1]));`

Comment: @useruser272933 Never knew about `System.setIn`. If you can write that as an answer, I'd certainly upvote it.

Comment: did write it as an answer!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way I did find is pass filename as argument to main function and add line like this:

```
if(args.length > 1)
    System.setIn(new FileInputStream(args[1]));
```